# Export Eclipse Maven Project with manually added Dependency

Tags: eclipse, maven

I would like to export and import on a different pc a maven eclipse project where I added a resource:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=/etc/jco-2.1/sapjco.jar -DgroupId=com.sap.mw.jco -DartifactId=jco2.1 -Dversion=2.1 -Dpackaging=jar
```

I don't want to do this on each pc where I import the project especially not because then I also have to download the resource give maven the path of it and so on. Does anybody know how to do this?

@Edit Respond to first comment:

I am not sure what you've were trying to say but I thought I added with the command above the jar to the local repository actually it is present in

```
~/home/username/.m2/repository/com/sap/mw/jco/*.lastUpdated
```

when I look into Eclipses Maven Repository View under "Local Repository" there is only located .../com/google .../com/sun .../thoughtworks

Can you tell me how I can add the dependency to the local repository? (the local repository path and the path in my filesystem where I checked if the files are existant is the same)

Will this fix my problem that jco2.1 is added to the archive when I export my project?

Comment: Start using a repository manager installed that artifact there and use it as a usual dependency no need to do that manually ever...

Comment: Can you explain more precisely what I should do?